# How to change some details on the passport application AFTER it got submitted?

Tags: uk, passports, uk-citizens

My sister wants to renew her British passport from overseas, she made two mistakes on her application form:

- wrong email
- missing middle name

Whats is the standard procedure to deal with a similar issue? re-send a new application form? send a letter?

For various reasons she could not get the right advice from the passport office when she phoned them, also they refused to discuss the issue with me as I am not the applicant.

Comment: I wonder if this might be better on [Expats](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/), as the procedure probably differs since you're applying from abroad?

Comment: @Gagravarr I have no idea but this is not an immigration question, she just want to renew her passport that's all.

Comment: @User Most likely, her passport will get declined and she will have to re-apply and documents sent to her. Or, they will see the information on the previous passport and correct it, doubtful, however.

Comment: It's just a passport renewal, a problem MANY international travellers face. Definitely on topic.

Comment: "could not get the right advice" - seems vague. Did they tell her what to do or not?

Comment: @MarkMayo different answers from different advisers, one said it's not possible, other said send us a letter. They were not helpful when I called them. I am not used to that in the British system, maybe because it's a highly sensitive matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What's is the standard procedure to deal with a similar issue?**

The 'standard procedure' is to initiate an enquiry through the facility sponsored by [HM Passport Office](https://eforms.homeoffice.gov.uk/outreach/Passport_Enquiries.ofml).  They provide a form with some drop-downs and ID fields.  Applications from abroad are normally referred to the Glasgow office for fulfillment, but it's fine to enter London...

[image]

At the bottom of the form there is a free text area to describe the nature of the enquiry; your sister should put here her correct email address and correct name.  They will revert if further clarifications are needed.

Comment: Totally off-topic, but you just caused me to check on your usage of "revert": http://english.stackexchange.com/a/10148/13944.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier, legalese...  a poor habit difficult to break...